# Int Argument Must be a String or a Number, Not a List, Python csv

Tags: python, csv, typeerror

```
def load_asn1_data(filename='songdata.csv'):
    import csv
    reader=csv.reader(open(filename,'r'))
    songs=[]
    for r in reader:
        songs.append(r)
    return songs
def fastest_year(songs):
    for row in songs:
        title = row[0]
        artist = row[1]
        year = int(row[2])
        tempo = float(row[3])
        artist_hotness=float(row[4])
        duration = float(row[5])
        key = int(row[6])
        loudness = float(row[7])
        mode = int(row[8])
    for speed in tempo:
        if tempo[speed]==max(tempo):
            print year[speed]

songs=load_asn1_data(filename='songdata.csv')
fastest_year(songs)
```

Update: So, now that I know that the first index refers to rows, I made a for-loop in which each variable corresponds to the value of a particular index in a row. If I try to run this, then I get a new error, float object is not iterable. I thought that maybe the max function doesn't work for floats, but I tested it, and it does. I'm confused, since I am interpreting my last for-loop as, for all elements in the "tempo class", if the tempo at that index is the largest, print the year associated with that tempo.

Comment: What is in `songdata.csv`?

Comment: Can you please execute `print(songs[2])` before `fastest_year(songs)` and show output?

Comment: what does songs[0] look like?  that is, give us one row to look at to understand the data format.  Most likely songs.csv is rows of songs with meta data in the columns; meaning songs[r] is just a row from the csv and songs[r][c] is a specific field in the csv.

Comment: songdata.csv is an excel spreadsheet with columns for title, artist, year, etc. I understand now that the first index is for rows (which is weird, since the code that was given doesn't make sense, then), so how can each variable in the fastest_year function to column lists as opposed to row lists?

Answer (score 0):

if this is the error you are receiving:

`TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'`

then your `songs[2]` might be like this `[2010]` or `[xxxx, xxxx]`

please check it by printing either `songs[2]` or `type(songs[2])`

please make it songs[2][0]

```
year = int(songs[2][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

`songs` is a list of lists, in the `fastest_year` function you're actually accessing rows, not columns. You will need to look through each row in `songs` to get the values you want. Something like:

```
songs=load_asn1_data(filename='songdata.csv')
for song in songs:
    fastest_year(song)
```

Although without knowing exactly what the code is meant to do I can't say if that will work exactly for your purposes.